# NSFetchedResults not updating automatically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm confused with this **NSFetchedResultsController**…

I have my whole app working, however some results don't get updated instantly. I have categories on all database entities.

One entitiy is **MainCategory** and each main category has several **subcategories**. And all **maincategories** get displayed in the **initial view.**

And the **subcategories** have all a **$-value**.

In the main view I display now the **sum** of all **subcategories** for each **main category.**

**This works.**

However if I **change** the values in the following views for the **subcategories**, the sum for all the **subcategories** in the **initial view** doesn't get updated.

`Why? What do I have to call for that to work?`

`This is the relevant line in my initial view:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MainCategoryCell";
    MainCategoryTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    // Configure the cell layout
    MainCategory *mainCategory = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.costs.text = [[mainCategory getMonthlyCostsOfAllSpendingCategories] getLocalizedCurrencyString];
}
```

`And this is how the fetched results controller got set up in the initial view:`

```
- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MainCategory"];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"position" ascending:YES]];
    [self.budgetDatabase.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                       managedObjectContext:self.budgetDatabase.managedObjectContext
                                                                         sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                  cacheName:nil];
}

-(void)useDocument
{
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:[self.budgetDatabase.fileURL path]]){
        [self.budgetDatabase saveToURL:self.budgetDatabase.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            [self setupFetchedResultsController];
            [self initializeDatabaseWithData];
        }];
    } else if (self.budgetDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed){
        [self.budgetDatabase openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){
            [self setupFetchedResultsController];
        }];
    } else if (self.budgetDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal){
        [self setupFetchedResultsController];
    }
}

-(void)setBudgetDatabase:(UIManagedDocument *)budgetDatabase
{
    if(_budgetDatabase != budgetDatabase){
        _budgetDatabase = budgetDatabase;
        [self useDocument];
    }
}



- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //Initialize database
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if(!self.budgetDatabase){
        NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentationDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
        [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"BudgetDatabase"];
        self.budgetDatabase = [[UIManagedDocument alloc]initWithFileURL:url];
    }
}
```

the FetchedResultsController:

```
#import "CoreDataViewController.h"

@interface CoreDataViewController()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL beganUpdates;
@end

@implementation CoreDataViewController

#pragma mark - Properties

@synthesize fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext = _suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext;
@synthesize debug = _debug;
@synthesize beganUpdates = _beganUpdates;
@synthesize reordering = _reordering;
@synthesize tableView = _tableView;

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - Fetching

- (void)performFetch
{
    if (self.fetchedResultsController) {
        if (self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate) {
            if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] fetching %@ with predicate: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entityName, self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate);
        } else {
            if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] fetching all %@ (i.e., no predicate)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entityName);
        }
        NSError *error;
        [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
        if (error) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] %@ (%@)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), [error localizedDescription], [error localizedFailureReason]);
    } else {
        if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] no NSFetchedResultsController (yet?)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)setFetchedResultsController:(NSFetchedResultsController *)newfrc
{
    NSFetchedResultsController *oldfrc = _fetchedResultsController;
    if (newfrc != oldfrc) {
        _fetchedResultsController = newfrc;
        newfrc.delegate = self;
        if ((!self.title || [self.title isEqualToString:oldfrc.fetchRequest.entity.name]) && (!self.navigationController || !self.navigationItem.title)) {
            self.title = newfrc.fetchRequest.entity.name;
        }
        if (newfrc) {
            if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), oldfrc ? @"updated" : @"set");
            [self performFetch];
        } else {
            if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] reset to nil", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] name];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [self.fetchedResultsController sectionForSectionIndexTitle:title atIndex:index];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.fetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles];
}

#pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    if(!self.reordering){
        if (!self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext) {
            [self.tableView beginUpdates];
            self.beganUpdates = YES;
        }
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
  didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    if(!self.reordering){
        if (!self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext)
        {
            switch(type)
            {
                case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                    [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                    break;
                    
                case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                    [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    if(!self.reordering){
        if (!self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext)
        {
            switch(type)
            {
                case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                    break;
                    
                case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                    break;
                    
                case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                    break;
                    
                case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    if(!self.reordering){
        if (self.beganUpdates) [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
}

- (void)endSuspensionOfUpdatesDueToContextChanges
{
    _suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext = NO;
}

- (void)setSuspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext:(BOOL)suspend
{
    if (suspend) {
        _suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext = YES;
    } else {
        [self performSelector:@selector(endSuspensionOfUpdatesDueToContextChanges) withObject:0 afterDelay:0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make yourself the delegate of the FRC. This will trigger it to observe the context for changes. You need to implement the delegate methods to reload the table view.

Comment: This doesn't help unfortunately since I already am the delegate..,

Comment: Ok, so are the delegate methods being called? Is the table view being triggered to update?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:
reload the table view at the end of this method:

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
  didChangeObject:(id)anObject
     atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
    newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath{
       ...
       ...

  [self.tableView reloadData]
  }